# Paper.js - Rotate segment points around a radius size

Tags: javascript, rotation, paperjs, rotational-matrices

I have an imported SVG in my paper.js project.

What i'm trying to do is to rotate each of the svg's segment points around a set radius, animating it with the `onFrame()` method.

I know how to position each segments point's x and y position but i cant really figure out how to position it in a 'rotation'.

What i have now :

[image]

```
var words = project.importSVG(document.querySelector("svg"));
words.visible = true; // Turn off the effect of display:none;;
words.position = view.center;

var letterR = words.children.letter_r;
var letterR_outside = letterR.children.letter_r_outside;
letterR_outside.selected = true;


var rotate_point = view.center;

function onFrame(event) {

  var _delta = Math.sin(event.time);

  //   console.log(Math.round(50 * Math.cos(theta[0])) * _delta);
  //   letterR_outside.segments[0].point.x = Math.round(_radius * Math.cos(theta[0]));
  //   letterR_outside.segments[0].point.y = Math.round(_radius * Math.sin(theta[0]));


  for (var i = 0; i < letterR_outside.segments.length; i++) {
    var segment = letterR_outside.segments[i];
    // segment.point.x += _delta;
    segment.point.rotate(3, rotate_point);
  }

}
```

Example of what i'm trying to achieve by rotating each points around a radius. [i made the black circles visible to show the rotation circle of each points]
[image]

I'm not exactly sure how to approach this. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: `point.rotate(angle, center)` is exactly what you need to rotate a point around a center. So I don't really understand what you need ; the rotation illustration is unclear to me... I see that you might want to [`fatten`](http://paperjs.org/reference/path/#flatten) your letters before rotating them, or [the segments with handles](http://paperjs.org/tutorials/paths/working-with-path-items/) will behave in a weird manner...

Comment: in my code as shown above, `point.rotate(angle, center)` on individual points actually does nothing. not sure why exactly.

applying it to the group parent rotates the entire letter in unison tho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling the [point.rotate()](http://paperjs.org/reference/point/#rotate-angle-center) does nothing because it returns a clone of the point and doesn't modify it directly.
See the documentation:

> Rotates the point by the given angle around an optional center point. **The object itself is not modified.** ...

So you might want to reasign the value:

```js
segment.point = segment.point.rotate(3, rotate_point);
```